# How to test my ETL pipeline entirely on Amazon Athena, given that there are no libraries or mocks for it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-athena

I am writing a huge big data ETL pipeline entirely written on AWS Athena and Python just orchestrating the athena queries, There are no unit testing frameworks or libraries which can help in mocking for example w.r.t AWS Athena. I would want to write unit tests and make sure my queries work as expected.

Comment: hello, i also wrote an etl file in athena, how do u call / schedule it . and how do you overwrite all the data in final table using athena

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wanted to test athena based code, without actual access to AWS. I ended up using moto - https://github.com/getmoto/moto

Moto helped me to mock S3 and other services, and for athena I extended the basic mock (which does nothing when you run a query or ask for query results).  I change the mock's default methods to my own:

```
from moto.athena.models import athena_backends
from moto.core import DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID

athena_backends[DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID]["us-east-1"].start_query_execution = _my_start_query_execution
athena_backends[DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID]["us-east-1"].get_query_results = _my_get_query_results
```